# Differentiated outputs, because of error

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

The problem that I occur has been different to solve for me, because I cannot find the solution. It works on my localost without any problems and error messages, but once I upload it to this webspace http://chris1904.bplaced.net/index.html I get the error message

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

and this is the line that the error points at

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
```

You can compare it to this site http://chris1904.webege.com/index.html 
It is the exact same source, but it is being interpreted differently.

I do not like to have syntax errors, even though they might be interpreted correctly, but how can I fix this error? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a javascript syntax error here:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: image,
                    title: compAddressArr[i],
                });
```

The trailing comma after the last item `title: compAddressArr[i],` will cause an error in IE.

Same thing again further down:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: completeAddress,
            });
```